# Ruby: Get value out of a string based on its position in the string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a huge string in the form of a hash

```
    {"id"=>213, "email"=>"123@test.com", "closed_at"=>nil, 
     "created_at"=>"2018-
      02-23T08:34:45-06:00", "updated_at"=>"2018-02-23T08:34:45-06:00", 
      "number"=>1149, 
      "note"=>nil, "token"=>"123456789", 
      "gateway"=>"paypal", 
      "product_id"=>"1231231231", 
      "test"=>false, "total_price"=>"9.99"}
```

I need to extract the value that is after `"product_id"` which in this example is `1231231231`

I tried converting this String into a hash using `eval()` but it wouldn't let me get the value when i would try `hash[:product_id]` or `hash['product_id']`

Is there any other way i can use that string and find something after the position of `"product_id"`. I am running out of ideas

EDIT: it was returning nil when i tried converting it to a hash, the string is being fetched from the database, i have a column that was suppose to be a jasonb and is being stored as a hash in a column of type 'character varying'

EDIT: Not sure why my question was downvoted i asked how i could extract something from a string and the question was answered.

Comment: Where is this string coming from? What does the object look like when coming out from `eval`?

Comment: What @EricDuminil said. Also, `eval` is `evil` (IMO). So, depending on the answer, you might be able to use `JSON.parse` or something similar to avoid the `evil` of `eval`.

Comment: "but it wouldn't let me get the value when i would try" what do you mean by that? are you getting an error or it's returning nil or what?

Comment: Who's generating this string? Who's supplying it to you? Why is it in this format? It really should be in a proper data format like JSON or YAML or pretty much *anything* other than Ruby code notation.

Comment: Sorry it was returning nil, the string is being fetched from the database, i have a column that was suppose to be a jasonb and is being stored as a hash in a column of type 'character varying'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input[/(?<="product_id"=>").*?(?=")/].to_i
#⇒ 1231231231
```

Comment: Love the symmetrical regex around product_id!

Comment: I learned something new today.  I didn't know you could pass a Regexp into String#[].  Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse should return a hash that you can use

```
hash = JSON.parse string <- this is your hash string
product_id = hash["product_id"]
```